# How to wait some seconds in C# Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, task

I have a function to create multiple tasks using `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

```
public void MultipleThread(List<string> list)
{
    List<Task> listTask = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string item in list)
    {
        listTask.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SetAddress(item)));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(listTask.ToArray());
}
```

How to wait some seconds before continue to execute next task?

Comment: You should be using `Task.Run()` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Also, it's not clear what you are wanting -- do you want a delay before the next iteration of the `foreach` loop, or do you want a delay inside the `Task`?

Comment: I have to wait all tasks complete, so I use Task.Factory.StartNew instead of Task.Run(). I want a delay before the next iteration of the foreach loop.

Comment: You can wait for the tasks exactly the same way when using `Task.Run`. If you just want a delay inside the loop then you're looking for `Thread.Sleep`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the other `WhaitAll` option that takes two arguments 
`array of tasks and milliseconds Timeout`.

```
public static bool WaitAll (System.Threading.Tasks.Task[] tasks, int millisecondsTimeout);



public void MultipleThread(List<string> list)
{
    List<Task> listTask = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string item in list)
    {
        listTask.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SetAddress(item)));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(listTask.ToArray(), 50000);
}
```

I hope this solves your problem

*** UPDATE ***

To make a gap in between each task run,
you can use the static   `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds`

```
Task t = Task.Run( () => {} ); 
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150);
if (! t.Wait(ts))
Console.WriteLine("The timeout interval elapsed.");
```

Comment: That is completely wrong. You are confusing the task wait timeout (which is the *maximum* time that your program will wait for a `Task` to complete before it cancels it) with a delay time (which is an *absolute* amount of time that your program will wait before continuing to the next statement). Your second example won't wait at all, because the empty task will complete immediately. The appropriate delay options are `Thread.Sleep()` and `Task.Delay()` depending on whether you are writing asynchronous code.

Comment: For the first example, you're right I was confused, thanks for describing.

Comment: The task is empty just for the example ;)